# Page_ClientValidate in undefined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have an asp.net user control which is plugged into both asp.net and MVC pages

When the control is on an asp.net page the client validation in it works fine but when the control is on an MVC page the following call in the js validation fails;

```
Page_ClientValidate('ValidationGroup');
```

with the error in Chrome: Object [object global] has no method 'Page_ClientValidate'

How can I get my client side validation to work on my mvc pages when the hyperlink button is clicked?

I need whatever the solution is to work across both MVC and ASP.Net as our site is a combination of the two

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page\_ClientValidate is Undefined (ASP.NET MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033672/page-clientvalidate-is-undefined-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, that post only talks about a site that is solely MVC, I need a resolution for a site that runs both MVC and ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
$('#Form').submit(function () {
    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        Page_ClientValidate();
        if (Page_IsValid == true) {
            alert('the form is valid');
        }
    } else {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            alert('the form is valid');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @MartinaL: that is why we are checking whether it is working or not before calling

Comment: Thanks Chamika sorry I misread that, trying this now. Only issue is while the user controls have asp:hyperlinks and input fields they are not contained within a form, clicking the hyperlink calls js (which is where the validation check needs to be done) that calls a HTTP (Ajax) request which adds to cart. so I won't be able to do the check on  form submit, I can do it in the add to cart js function but I won't be able to use $(this).valid() - as this will not be the form

Comment: so you can try this '$(this).valid()' => '$('#Form').valid()'

Comment: While this fix works for me original issue (thanks Chamika) if you see below I now have a new issue that has arisen

Answer (score 0):

What Kind of validations are you trying to do?

*first option:*

MVC gives you great tool for validations:
Have you heard about "Data Annotations" tool? 
as you configure your model fields you can use the common validation annotation called "required" for example:

Model:

```
[Required ("ID Field is Required")]
public int ID {get; set;}
```

View:

```
@html.texboxfor(m=>m.ID)
@validatefor((m=>m.ID)
```

and on the view you'll see a red message next the the input field you're trying to validate.

you can change the default messages design and location using CSS.

There is a good Tutorial for that matter at:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

there is more data annotation validations, it depends on what kind of validations are you trying to do..

*Second option:*

you can use validate.js for input validations - it gives you the ability to validate almost any kinds of inputs - from numbers and strings to tables, and you can custom you own validation rules...

*Default Option:*

Build your Own Validation Method using native js for example:

```
if( $(.myClass).length<0 )
   {
     alert( "Please Insert Value" );
     return false;
   }
```

## EDIT:

you can create :

View:

```
@using("actionMethod","controller")
{
<!--Content contains "names" of tags-->
<input type="submit"/>
}
```

OR

```
<a href="@html.URL("text","actionMethod","controller" new{ "names" of tags })"></a>
```

Controller:

When post back occurred , check the names and return to the same View, if the names are not satisfy.

## end EDIT

If you have more questions, please ask.

Hope I Helped, Good luck.

Comment: MVC may well but the control is not used only in MVC pages it is also used in WebForms pages so this will not work. The control is an asp.net webforms usercontrol which is used in both webforms and mvc pages but the validation is in the control itself so i need some way to trigger a check of this validation from and MVC page

Comment: As I said this control is an asp.net user control (ie not an mvc partial view) which is being used on both standard asp.net pages AND MVC views. So I can't use the standard MVC validaiton as it is also used on ASP.Net web forms pages and I can't use Page_ClientValidate as it doesn't work on MVC. surely there must be some way to get the click of an asp:Hyperlink within an ASP.Net User Control to trigger validation on both an MVC page and an ASP.Net Web Forms page?

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to use an MVC Razor validation method on an ascx web forms user control that is being embedded in an MVC View using RenderPartial?

The problem I now have is that my ascx user control has a custom validation control on it (just the standard web forms custom validator) and when this control is used on an MVC View (by using Render Partial) the view errors with the following error;

Control 'ctl00_ProductListView_ctrl5_ctl00_ctl00_valValueMultiple' of type 'CustomValidator' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

This is because the MVC view doesn't have a form on it obviously but I can't simply add one.

I cant'simply change this from an ascx web forms user control because it is dynamically added to both MVC and Web Forms pages (we have a mixed site of MVC and Web Forms - this is beyond my control) throughout our website.

Comment: Ok, I have successfully been able to add a Html.BeginForm to the MVC View page that the ascx is appearing on but it hasn't fixed this issue unfortunately

Comment: So I believe my only option is, if it is possible, is to somehow use an MVC compatible validation method within my ascx to replace the ASP.Net Web Forms Custom Validator (that is added via codebehind in c#)??